# How to use '«' in filenames with PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8

I have such PHP code:

```
$bytes_written = file_put_contents('./files/' . $name . '.pdf', fopen($url, 'r'));
echo $name . PHP_EOL;
```

And `echo` gives me `ТОВ «Фірма «Технокомплекс»` but filename is `ТОВ &#171;Фірма &#171;Технокомплекс&#187;.pdf` But I can manual rename this file via FTP and this files name is accepted. So is there any way not to replace `«` into `&#171;` when writting files with PHP?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm. It looks like I just should use [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)